# How to login use sha1() password from database in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter, im insert a registration from to database.they have username and password. that password is encrypted one using sha1().and save to database.
Controller .php

```
$register['email']=$this->input->post("email");
$register['username']=$this->input->post("username");
$register['password']=sha1($this->input->post("password"));             
$this->load->model("Register_Model");
$this->Register_Model->create($register);
header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/Register/Login/");
```

Model.php

```
public function create($register)
{ 
 $this->db->insert('registers',$register);
 return true;
}
```

its working.but my login is not working .

Controller.php

```
$login['username']=$this->input->post("username");
$login['password']=$this->input->post("password");      

$this->load->model("Register_Model");
$result=$this->Register_Model->login($login);
$resultdata = $result->row_array();
```

Model.php

```
public function login($login)
{
    $username=$login['username'];
    $password=$login['password'];
    $value=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
    return $this->db->get_where('registers',$value);
}
```

problem is password field.
how to solve??

Comment: DO NOT use weak or broken hashing algorithms like MD5 or SHA1.

These algorithms are old, proven to be flawed, and not designed for password hashing in the first place. Use password_hash

Comment: how to use password_hash??

Comment: soory im beginner in codeigniter

Comment: $register['password']=password_hash($this->input->post("password"),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  Use password_verify to check from database

Comment: I would not use sha1 or md5 for passwords use php password_hash and verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use your code like this encrypt your password input from sha1 and then run the query **$password=sha1($login['password']);** 

Model.php

```
public function login($login)
{
    $username=$login['username'];
    $password=sha1($login['password']);
    $value=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
   return  $this->db->get_where('registers',$value);

}
```

Controller.php

```
    $login['username']=$this->input->post("username");
                    $login['password']=$this->input->post("password");      
                    $this->load->model("Register_Model");
                    $result=$this->Register_Model->login($login);
                    $resultdata = $result->row_array(); 

                    if(!empty($resultdata)){
                     //set the session and redirect to desired page
}else{
//other wise redirect to login page with error message
}
```

Comment: im try it.. but it redirect the same login page ..my action controller is public function login_action().

Comment: @Alexyui... check again my code . i modified my code

Comment: Thanks....its your modifing code is  works... only change if condition  if(!empty($resultdata))

Comment: ok ,but my session is not working after modified my code.
                    $resultdata = $result->row_array(); 
              if(!empty($resultdata))
               {
                   $this->load->view('register/login');
               }
               else{
              $this->session->set_userdata('username', $resultdata['username']);
 $userid= $resultdata['username']; $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$userid);                header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/Register/userhome/"); }

Comment: my userhome page code is ...<?php $userid=$this->session->userdata('userid');?>
       <p align="right"><b><font size="4px" color="black">Welcome</font><font size="4px" color="red"> <?php echo $userid;?></font></b></p>

Comment: if(!empty($resultdata)) { $this->session->set_userdata('username', $resultdata['username']); $userid= $resultdata['username']; $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$userid); header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/Register/userhome/"‌​); } else{ $this->load->view('register/login'); }

you just interchange the value of if and else condition ..the code you put in else ...this should be in if condition....use this code...

Comment: that imaslo try it ..but not work .it redirect to controller  login_action function.but the your previous code is working ,go to userhome page ..but session only seen welcome ,no have username.

Comment: only session getting issue

Comment: try to print $resultdata array before setting up the session and check

Comment: no value ..which means only redirection ..not session value passed.

Comment: sir,this condition is right?? if(!empty($resultdata)) i think this line is the problem

Comment: im using the 1st code without password sha1 method.all are working properly session is working.

Comment: if(!empty($resultdata)) this line of code saying if $resultdata having value means it is not empty and user is valid and in if condition we set session and otherwise $resultdata is empty then user detail is wrong or some problem is there ...then we redirect to again login page

Comment: that ok sir .. but why values are not passing ??

Comment: im command $password=sha1($login['password']); from model and wrote $password=($login['password']);and also if($resultdata==0){...} then run ...working perfect..session pass value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143664/discussion-between-rajat-gupta-and-alexyui).

Answer (score 0):

Edited.
I see in your login function of controller not encrypted sha1

```
$login['password']=sha1($this->input->post("password"));
```

and u can try write login function in model like below

```
public function login($login) {
$this->db->where('username', $login['username']);
$this->db->where('password', $login['password']);
$this->db->from('registers');
return $this->db->get();
}
```

And i think u should validator your data after u query for sure not get sqlinject or xss,... something like that.

Comment: iam use above code inmy model  ...i got an error Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)